# Eb tools with multiple aws accounts

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-sdk

Is it possible to use Elastic Beanstalk Tools with two separate aws accounts in the same machine?

More description:

After installing elastic beanstalk tools as described [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-install.html), I am able to initialize the setup in my project using

```
eb init
```

and supplying the aws id and secret. Everything is fine at this point.
The issue here is that the credentials are automatically stored in ~/.aws/config and are read whenever the eb command is executed.

I have a second AWS account and would like to use eb tools there as well. Is it possible to make eb tools use a custom config file? I couldn't find anything in the documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-reference-get-started.html)

Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can do multiple profiles using EB tools.

To create a new profile, you can use

```
aws configure --profile <your-profile-name>
```

It will generate a new profile inside `~/.aws/credentials` and `~/.aws/config`. Or, you can edit those file manually. Please read the documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html).

After you generate the profile, you can append `--profile <your-profile-name>` to your `eb init` command:

```
eb init --profile <your-profile-name>
```

It will generate a config file (`.elasticbeanstalk/config.yml`). After that, if you want to deploy, just use:

```
eb deploy
```